# Is there a way to visualize the webpack dependency graph in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am currently working on a NextJS application and would like to visualize the dependency graph in my application.

Is there any tool or library which could help me achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer